# Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, classpath

i am using eclipse mars
with hibernate-release-5.0.7.Final
with postgreSQL

i m getting that error mentioned in error 
i m attaching code with it plzz help me i am new with hibernate.

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HIbernet Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="login" method="post">
ID: <input type="text" name="txt1"><br>
Name: <input type="text" name="txt2"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!--
  ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>.

-->

<hibernate-configuration><session-factory>

<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc</property>
<property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="connection.password">admin</property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

<!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
<mapping class="org.myapp.clg.dto.Vai"/>

</session-factory></hibernate-configuration>
```

login.java

```
package org.myapp.clg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.myapp.clg.dto.Vai;

@WebServlet(description = "login controller", urlPatterns = { "/login" })
public class login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public login() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session s1 = sf.openSession();
        pw.println("id:"+ request.getParameter("txt1")+"/nname:"+ request.getParameter("txt2"));

        try
        {
        Vai v1 = new Vai();
        v1.setUid(1);
        v1.setName("vaibhav");      
        s1.beginTransaction();
        s1.save(v1);
        s1.getTransaction().commit();
        s1.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            pw.println(ex);
            s1.getTransaction().rollback();
            s1.close();
        }
    }
}
```

4 vai.java

```
package org.myapp.clg.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity 
public class Vai {

    @Id
    private int Uid;
    private String name;
    public int getUid() {
        return Uid;
    }
    public void setUid(int uid) {
        Uid = uid;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

i am using servlet and JSP for this n on console i m getting this error discription:

```
Feb 11, 2016 1:34:51 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}
Feb 11, 2016 1:34:51 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 11, 2016 1:34:51 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 11, 2016 1:34:51 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Feb 11, 2016 1:34:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 11, 2016 1:34:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [org.myapp.clg.login] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.myapp.clg.login.doPost(login.java:28)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 47 more
```

m stuck on it :( plz help me

this is image :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look at the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver
```

The prostgresql Driver class is missing in your classpath.
[Download](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/) it and add it to your classpath.

or if you use maven add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version><your version></version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i have it in my class path

Comment: @vats it doesn't lock so. How you are runing your code?

Comment: @vats you are running in eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

do Build path and add mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar file and run again.

Comment: Please add an explanation for  "why your answer solves the problem?"